# Things to consider before baking components

Tags: safety

I will be using my own baking oven for components/ICs. What I only know is the baking conditions of MSL devices as per Jedec or as per required baking conditions as per MSL label of the part.

For example, MSL 3 devices needs to bake for 24 hours @ 125 deg C.

Do i need to heat my oven first until it reached 125 deg C and put my parts and count for 24 hours or I can put the parts straight away and wait for 24 hrs to complete the baking?

Answer (score 1):

Moisture sensitive devices are packaged in a moisture barrier antistatic bag with a desiccant and a moisture indicator card which is sealed.

According to IPC, Moisture/reflow sensitivity classification for plastic Integrated circuit (IC) SMDs,floor life out of the bag for MSL 3 devices is 168 hours. So, you can mount them without baking even after 6 days of floor life.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your parts have been out of the bag long enough to require baking, then the correct method is to preheat the oven.

That said, you will probably be fine if you just put the parts in the oven and turn it on. You might want to add an hour for oven warm up time.

Make sure your oven temperature does not get too high and violate the storage temperature specification on the datasheet.